# Python retrieve individual item from fetchone()

Tags: python

I have a SQL query in python like so to retrieve the first, fourth, and fifth column elements if it exists

```
cur2.execute('SELECT * FROM duplicates where TITLE=?', [post_title])   
sql2.commit()
if cur2.fetchone():
    repost_permalink = cur.fetchone()[0]
    repost_title = cur.fetchone()[3]
    repost_submitter = cur.fetchone()[4]
```

Forr some reason I keep getting the error:

```
repost_permalink = cur.fetchone()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Am I accessing the element incorrectly?

Comment: is `cur` correct? You seem to be executing the query on `cur2` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `fetchone()`, it fetches another row.  So you are fetching four different rows in your code, because you call `fetchone` four times.  If there aren't that many rows in the result set, some of them will be None.

If you want to get parts of a single row, store the row and then access it:

```
row = cur2.fetchone()
if row:
    repost_permalink = row[0]
    repost_title = row[3]
    repost_submitter = row[4]
```

Comment: You were right. My first mistake was confusing cur and cur2.